# How to rescan USB device?

Tags: usb, umount

Since when I use The Files to umount the USB device(not console umount command), ubuntu will also remove the block device, I can't click to mount that again. If I don't want to unplug and plug the USB device, How to let the Ubuntu rescan that?

Comment: if your device have been powered down, you must replug it. If not `sudo lsusb` should do the trick

Answer (score 6):

you can use usbreset.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then you need source for this little tool
copy the text from [here](https://marc.info/?l=linux-usb&m=121459435621262&q=p3)
and save it as `usbreset.c` 
Change to directory where the downloaded file is

```
cc usbreset.c -o usbreset
```

Move the build file to /usr/local/bin/

```
sudo mv usbreset /usr/local/bin/
```

These way you can use it.
Identify your stick or whatever with

```
lsusb
```

I show an example.

```
Bus 003 Device 022: ID 18a5:0304 Verbatim, #Ltd my Stick
```

To reset this

```
usbreset /dev/bus/usb/003/022
```

Comment: your username is legendary